# Interpretation of Output

Tags: r, cross-validation

Here is the R code that produced the output below:

```
library(caret)
set.seed(934)
fitControl <- trainControl(method= "repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=10)
logitfit <- train(z~ a+b+c+d+e, data=train, method="glm", trControl = fitControl)
logitfit
```

Consider the following output from R:

```
Generalized Linear Model 

900 samples
 20 predictors
  2 classes: '0', '1' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 10 times) 

Summary of sample sizes: 846, 847, 846, 845, 847, 846, ... 

Resampling results

  Accuracy  Kappa  Accuracy SD  Kappa SD
  0.80     0.58  0.076       0.18
```

This is a logistic regression model using a 10-fold cross validation repeated 10 times. Does the output above indicate that the average accuracy is 0.80?

Comment: @Glen_b: Edited above.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you did this for just one set of tuning parameters so yes your average accuracy over the 10 folds in 0.8.

You can also try different tuning parameters, for example

```
gbmGrid <-  expand.grid(interaction.depth = c(1, 5, 9),
                        n.trees = (1:30)*50,
                        shrinkage = 0.1)
gbmFit2 <- train(Class ~ ., data = training,
                 method = "gbm",
                 trControl = fitControl,
                 verbose = FALSE,
                 ## Now specify the exact models 
                 ## to evaludate:
                 tuneGrid = gbmGrid)
gbmFit2
```

which yields the output

```
Stochastic Gradient Boosting 

157 samples
 60 predictors
  2 classes: 'M', 'R' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 10 times) 

Summary of sample sizes: 142, 142, 140, 142, 142, 141, ... 

Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  interaction.depth  n.trees  Accuracy  Kappa  Accuracy SD  Kappa SD
  1                  50       0.77      0.53   0.1          0.2     
  1                  100      0.78      0.56   0.095        0.19    
  1                  150      0.79      0.58   0.094        0.19    
  ...
```

So you can see that the accuracy score is different for every set of tuning parameters. You would then select the set which gives you the best accuracy.

Comment: But there are no tuning parameters for the glm method.

Comment: that's fine, then ignore the latter part of the post and you final accuracy is 0.8